# Django and models / views, AttributeError

Tags: django

I am stuck with my miniportfolio in django, not sure what the error is telling me.

models.py

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    content = models.TextField()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/%s" % self.slug

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

def __repr__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py

```
def page_view(request, **kwargs):
    slug = kwargs.get('slug')
    page = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=slug)   
    content = page.content
    title = page.title
    return render_to_response("base.html", {"content":content, "title":title})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<page>)/$', page_view),
```

I get some really weird urls when I create a new page from the admin interface. 
127.0.0.1:3020/admin/r/7/3/ <-- I do not know why they are like this. Tips?
When I visit the pages I've created I get a 404.

Comment: first of all you are not using my_view, becuase of the direct_to_template in your urls.py ... if you were using it, it woudl have returned an error (content and title are not defined in that function) ... the attribute error that you see links to a different url as far as i can tell, so you should paste your entire urls and relevant code

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/r/7/1/ - This is the link the is generating for a page I create. I also changed my_view as above.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('page', (), {
    'slug': self.slug,
    'id': self.id,
    })
```

to something like:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/APP_URL_PATH/%s/" % self.slug # or use id, there's no need for two unique identifiers
```

and

```
def my_view(request, slug, id):
    page = get_object_or_404(pk=id)
```

to something like:

```
def my_view(request, **kwargs):
    slug = kwargs.get('slug')
    page = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=slug)
```

Your indention is probably bad because of copy pasting, you might want to edit your post. Have a look at django's documentation for an idea on url capture groups

Comment: I am still getting errors, but now the problem seems to me to be in the urls.py. Is my slug incorrect then?

Comment: your urlconf makes no sense, have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: url(r'^(?P<page>)/$', page_view) - Am I getting closer here?

Answer (score 0):

```
def page_view(request, **kwargs):
    slug = kwargs.get('page') # hello page! I found you
...
```

because you use `page` for variable not `slug` in urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<page>)/$', page_view),
```

---

Or you can write view like

```
def page_view(request, page=None):
    page_from_db = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=page)
    return render(request, "base.html", {"page": page_from_db})
```

in tpl

```
{{ page.content }}
```

---

And if you use 1.4 use `from django.shortcuts import render`

[render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) automatically use context